# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference In Android ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

ReactNative:0.61.4 
ReactNativeMaps:0.26.1
Android: 7 ~ 10

I found an error in FireBase `Crashlytics` while using ReactNativeMaps.

```
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.m.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@200616061@20.06.16 (100300-0):5)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@200616061@20.06.16 (100300-0):12)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@200616061@20.06.16 (100300-0):1)
ch.onTransact (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@200616061@20.06.16 (100300-0):4)
android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:692)
com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzb (unkonwSource:20)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzai.zza (unkonwSource:5)
com.google.android.gms.maps.zzm.onLocationChanged (unkonwSource:2)
com.airbnb.android.react.maps.FusedLocationSource$1.onSuccess (FusedLocationSource.java:46)
com.airbnb.android.react.maps.FusedLocationSource$1.onSuccess (FusedLocationSource.java:43)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run (unkonwSource:4)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:205)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6996)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

I don't know where the rest of the code is
Because only `FusedLocationSource` is known
I saw `FusedLocationSource` but `android.location.Location.getLatitude ()` doesn't exist.

```
package com.airbnb.android.react.maps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Looper;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class FusedLocationSource implements LocationSource {

    private final FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClientProviderClient;
    private final LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    public FusedLocationSource(Context context){
        fusedLocationClientProviderClient =
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority){
        locationRequest.setPriority(priority);
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval){
        locationRequest.setInterval(interval);
    }

    public void setFastestInterval(int fastestInterval){
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(final OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
        fusedLocationClientProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                onLocationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(location);
            }
        });
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    onLocationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(location);
                }
            }
        };
        fusedLocationClientProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        fusedLocationClientProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }
}
```

I know this is an error that occurs inside `onSuccess`, but I don't know how to fix it. Help.

Answer (score 0):

check runtime permission for Android. May be this is an issue of permission and due to that you are not able to get location value.